# Build Android L error after upgrade system today

Tags: android, compiling

I update system today,and i found that i can't build Android L successfully anyhow. Build error log as follow:

```
Completed secimage signed appsbl (logs in out/target/product/msm8994/secimage.log)
Yacc: aidl <= frameworks/base/tools/aidl/aidl_language_y.y
prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/bison/bison -d  -o out/host/linux-x86/obj32/EXECUTABLES/aidl_intermediates/aidl_language_y.cpp frameworks/base/tools/aidl/aidl_language_y.y
prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/bison/bison: m4 subprocess got fatal signal 11
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj32/EXECUTABLES/aidl_intermediates/aidl_language_y.cpp] Error 1

#### make failed to build some targets (01:09 (mm:ss)) ####
```

And dmesg log as follow:

```
[ 6819.986638] m4[4913]: segfault at fd80f2d0 ip 00000000fd80f2d0 sp 0000000002541a50 error 14 in ld-2.19.so[2adbfd80e000+23000]
```

So we can see that is the issue of m4.

Please find out what can i do?Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It seems kernel 3.13.0-59-generic caused this issue.
Downgrading to 3.13.0-57-generic fixed it.

Comment: It would be nice if you could elaborate your answer a bit and include e.g. a reference, instructions, etc... Thank you!

Comment: Yeah..lol. Good suggestion.

Comment: The latest 3.13.0-61-generic is OK now.

Answer (score 0):

**peyo-hd**'s answer is correct!!!

I faced the same issue today.
And I fixed it by doing the flowing steps.

1. Open grub2 default config

   ```
   sudo vim /etc/default/grub
   ```
2. Comment out the two lines and set a proper timeout

   ```
   # GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
   # GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
   GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
   ```
3. Update grub

   ```
   sudo update-grub2
   ```
4. Reboot and select the older kernel

Comment: Thank you for your help. Ubuntu has pushed a new package yesterday evening, and this issue is resolved.